# jQuery Mobile Beta 1 now shows the page as a normal website in mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have today updated to jQuery Mobile Beta 1 and now in my mobile (Android) and even some iPhone i tested on the page is shows like in my desktop browser = need to zoom to read stuff.

I can not find that they changed anything about how it works with that?

Its worked fine in latest alpha before i updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery Mobile is not inserting the `meta viewport` tags by default anymore. you have to insert it yourself.

See: *Dynamic injected viewport meta tag: Support dropped* in the [**release notes**](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/06/20/jquery-mobile-beta-1-released/)

Comment: I haven't looked at the beta release yet but I was thinking this might be the case, Thanks naugtur! +1

Comment: aye, well spotted - got bit by this as well.  I guess that'll teach me not to read the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up the meta tag that needs to be inserted is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```